# OpenStack_Swift_Installtion

Tags: installation, openstack, openstack-swift

can anybody upload to date swift installation document as everything single document is outdated.I have been trying to deploy openstack swift but cant get the swift working because instruction are not clear so can anyone please direct me to the swift up to date documents

Answer (score 0):

@emporio

My suggestion would be to go ahead and try [SAIO Swift deployment guide](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/development_saio.html), its updated.

Hope it helps.